# Javascript Explanation - Syntax/format/style is new to me

Tags: javascript

Im used to the syntax of javascript functions like this:

```
function sample()
{

}


<input type="text" onclick="sampe()" />
```

a simple onclick even to call the javascript function above. I have found a code on the internet on how to dynamically add textbox, now i want to make my own version of it but to make that i need to understand it first. My left eye cannot see clearly anymore, so it really makes it hard and demotivating for me to search and read every guide. If its not too much, if someone could explain to me how the following code works(FLOW) i would really appreciate it. I also dont understand the onclick event made only to the add button but not the others yet those 2 other buttons still does call the function.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery add / remove textbox example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            if (counter > 10) {
                alert("Only 10 textbox allowed");
                return false;
            }
            $('<div/>',{'id':'TextBoxDiv' + counter}).html(
                $('<label/>').html( 'Textbox #' + counter + ' : ' ))
                    .append( $('<input type="text">').attr({'id':'textbox' + counter,'name':'textbox' + counter}) )
                    .appendTo( '#TextBoxesGroup' );
            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textox to remove");
                return false;
            }
            counter--;
            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
        });

        $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
                msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
            }
            alert(msg);
        });
    });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
 <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='textbox1' />
 </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton' onclick="dynamictext()"/>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton' />
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue' />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for your vision problems, but SO is not here to outsource any issues you have with reading code. (Which I'd still blame mostly on your unfamiliarity with Javascript) Get a good text editor that will highlight matching brackets for you, and consider extracting the anyonymous functions in the code into named ones to reduce the levels of nesting.

Comment: Also, your first example is the so-called "traditional" (or rather the "inline") event registration model. (See: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) It's fallen out of favour because it tangles up Javascript code with HTML and bloats your markup, and doesn't really make sense conceptually. (The term "events" implies that each event can have more than one handlers instead of just one code snipped.) The second example registers the events using jQuery, which is similar to the native "advanced" registration models: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips and guides. much appreciated, am currently sifting through youtube looking for good js tutorials there

Comment: QuirksMode is, in general, a decent resource if you want to understand the basic concepts of Javascript/browser interaction in the proper historical context - i.e. to see the difference between the "old" ways of doing something and the "new" ones. (Where searching for Javascript tutorials will usually give you a mix of both without relating the alternatives.) This obviously as an addition to good resources like http://www.webplatform.org/ and the documentation for libraries used in the code you're reading. (In your case, jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: @elclanrs 

May i ask though, why do most people use jquery for advanced stuffs like building interactive slideshows? I searched one for myself and most of the results tend to be jquery. I was under the impression that jquery is the new thing.

Comment: @elclanrs I now that jQuery is built on javascript so use it not the javascript itself because of differences between browsers, not to repeat that check if it is IE else if chrome else if firefox else if safari....

Comment: @user1891608 I'm not sure it's up to SO users to justify the decisions  of random tutorial authors on the internet. I use jQuery a lot because uhh... I like it? Or because: the features it provides are worth spending the time to learn it. (E.g. papering over browser inconsistencies, delegated events, promise-based asynchronous code, the jQuery UI components.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an "inline" event hander:

```
onclick="dynamictext()"
```

In this case, the function named dynamictext is called when the button is clicked. However, since you did not define the dynamictext function, an Exception is thrown. If you want to see the exception, open Chrome and press ctrl+shift+J to open the console and then run your code. When you click the button, the console will say "Uncaught ReferenceError: dynamictext is not defined." Note: inline event handlers are generally considered bad practice, because they do not separate behavior (which should be defined in JavaScript) from content (which can be defined in html for static content or JavaScript for dynamic content).

Take note that you DO NOT have to assign an `onclick` handler in your html AND your JavaScript. It is sufficient to assign a handler only in your html or only in your JavaScript. (However, if you assign a handler in your html, you still must define the function that you assigned (e.g., "dynamic text" in this case), which you failed to do in your code.

The Javascript code you provided defines onclick handlers for your three buttons. Here I show one of them:

```
$("#addButton").click(function () { // This anonymous function (function without a name),
        if (counter > 10) {         // is executed when the button with id="addButton"
            alert("Only 10 textbox allowed");  // is clicked
            return false;
        }
        $('<div/>', {
            'id': 'TextBoxDiv' + counter
        }).html(
        $('<label/>').html('Textbox #' + counter + ' : '))
            .append($('<input type="text">').attr({
            'id': 'textbox' + counter,
            'name': 'textbox' + counter
            })) // It is safer to always use semicolons. You should put one here.
```

If you look carefully, your will notice that the anonymous function is being passed as an argument to jQuery's "click" method. The click method adds a function(s) that will be executed when the click event of the currently selected element(s) (i.e., `button#addButton` ) is triggered (i.e., when someone clicks the element).

Comment: Is this script running on jquery functions? if so, must explain why it looked so new to me. I only used javascript as a means of validating forms. Thanks for this. I understand it better now.

Comment: This script is using the JQuery framework. `$("#addButton)` is "the" jQuery function (notice the name of the function is the dollar symbol). In this case, the jQuery function will find and return the DOM element with `id="addButton"` wrapped in a jQuery object. You can then call methods of that jQuery object to work with the selected DOM element. In this instance, a handler is attached to the `onclick` event of the DOM element.